# removing duplicate values from a column

Tags: excel

I am having trouble removing duplicate values from a column, I would usually do this in python but I don't have access to the environment unfortunately.

I cant figure out how to remove duplicate values from this column.

```
DIR
Output
Output
Input
Output
Input
Input
Input
Input
Output
```

I need to remove the `Output` from the column and leave that place empty, so ideally the end result would look like this

```
DIR


Input

Input
Input
Input
Input
```

Thank you very much, I know this is a noob question, please forgive :)

Comment: So you want to remove *all* instances of a word, which you specify first, from a column?

Comment: yes, exactly... sorry for not clarifying it better

Comment: Why not simply use `Find` and `Replace`? And if you want the VBA code instead then you can also record your doings and Excel / VBE will write the code for you.

Comment: omg thank you, I completely forgot about that :D, You just made my life so much easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your data range and press `Ctrl` + `F` then click replace tab.

There you should insert the word `Output` and click `Replace All`
[image]

Comment: D'oh! I completely overlooked that and had a macro all written up that loops through cells. This is probably the best way, nice thinking.